# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error using Selenium ChromeDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new in selenium  and i am trying to open a page so chome open but it can not load URL.

Code trials:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ecli\\chromedriver.exe")
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

I tried re install chrome, add `thread.sleep(5000)`, add dependency `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();` and `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

After close the chrome I have this:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.134 (8ec6fce403b3feb0869b0732eda8bd95011d333c-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#1262}) on port 54404
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'PC', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:264)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:49)
    at PrimerEjercicio.main(PrimerEjercicio.java:29)
```

Environment:

- OS: W10
- Chrome version :104.0.5112.102
- jve1.8.0_101 (java version)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642913/5372079

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=104.0*
- But you are using *chromedriver=103.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=103.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.134/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 103

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=103.0* and the *chrome=104.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.4.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v104.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=104.0* (as per [chromedriver=104.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/notes.txt)).

Comment: Hi ! The problema was " management by your organization" after all i could fix.